# SeoShop API + how to check existing product by name in PHP with curl?

Tags: php, curl

In SEOSHOP API ([documentation](http://developers.seoshop.com/api/resources/product#get-retrieve-a-product)), I can check the product from that product ID from API and want to check product by its product name not by ID.

How can I do this?